# Added a custom class to menu item on wordpress but hover not working?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've recently created a menu item in my wordpress menu, that I have styled differently, so that it looks like a call to action button as appose to a navigation item.

I went to menus > then css classes (on the item) and added `callout-button`

I then added the following to my themes custom CSS,

```css
.callout-button a {
  background-color: #8E3D86;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.callout-button a:hover {
  background-color: #b8b8b8 !important;
  border: 1px solid #8E3D86;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
  transition: width all 400ms;
}

.callout-button a:after {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Now this does correctly style the button, however the `:hover` doesn't work properly, the background colour isn't changing and is also adding an extra border (which is part of my normal menus css)

Does anyone have any ideas on how i can make this override the normal menu css?

Comment: Maybe the style that "catched" has also `!important`

Comment: Can you share the element hierarchy? Or the different relevant css rules?

Comment: Surely you have to be more specific than the css rule that prints the hover state.
Try to copy that rule and add the callput-button class where is need